# Azure Cognitive search custom filter problems

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'm using **Azure Cognitive** Search and I've encountered a problem.

I have a product schema that already has a boost property, but we want to add another boosting property specific to the product category.

Initially, we tried to add a **'sponsorRating'** property to the product so we could simply order by this property. However, we realized this approach wouldn't work because if a product appears in two different categories, it will be boosted in both.

Does anyone know if there's a way to order by **'sponsorRating'** and also check if the searched category matches the designated boosted category?

We are looking to position our sponsored products in the category at the top of the search but not filter the other products.

Our product schema is as follows:

ProductId - **'string'**
ProductName - **'string'**
ProductCategories - **'string[]'**
SponsorRating - **'decimal'** (this is the new addition)

Initially, we tried to add a **'sponsorRating'** property to the product so we could simply order by this property. However, we realized this approach wouldn't work because if a product appears in two different categories, it will be boosted in both.

Comment: could you provide the details package you used? Please share the code

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to achieve your goal of positioning sponsored products in the category at the top of the search results while not filtering out other products, is by utilize scoring profiles in Azure Cognitive Search.
Scoring profiles allow you to define custom scoring logic for search results, which can include boosting certain properties.

In your case, you can create a scoring profile that boosts products with a specific category and sponsor rating.

For more details you can check [Add scoring profiles to boost search scores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-scoring-profiles).